# Filter Bing Custom search results based on Date

Tags: api, filter, bing, bing-custom-search

I am trying to sort the search results returned from Bing Custom Search based on the **Date published**.

I checked the documentation and found a query parameter called "**freshness**" for Bing Web search from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v7-reference#query-parameters

Is it possible to do this using Bing Custom Search?
[image]